# Why does Google unescape their Analytics tracking code?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Just getting off my JavaScript training wheels.

Why does Google choose to `unescape` the `document.write` line in **Part 1** below?

Why don't they just write it like this? Maybe `unescape` is required for some older browser compatibility?

```
document.write('<script src="'
    + gaJsHost
    + 'google-analytics.com/ga.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
```

For reference, the entire Google Analytics tracking code looks like this:

**Part 1:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol)
    ? "https://ssl."
    : "http://www."
);
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='"
    + gaJsHost
    + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"
));
</script>
```

**Part 2:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try
{
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-0000000-0");
    pageTracker._trackPageview();
}
catch(err){}
</script>
```

I understand what the rest of the code does, just curious about the unescape part.

**Edit**

The bottom line is, `unescape` is required. Voted to close this question because it is a duplicate (see answer marked correct).

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the advantage of using unescape on document.write to load javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224670/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-unescape-on-document-write-to-load-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> It means the code will work in XML / XHTML and HTML without having to mess with CDATA

Please see:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224670/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-unescape-on-document-write-to-load-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224670/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-unescape-on-document-write-to-load-javacript)

Comment: Nice find on the previously answered question. Though it can still be made to work with both XHTML and HTML "without having to mess with CDATA" and without needing `unescape`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728697/javascript-external-script-loading-strangeness/729072#729072

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is when `</script`> is found even inside the quotes `"</script>"`
the parser wrongly understood that, its reach end of the script, so they cannot do like `"</script>"`

And Google wants to make sure variables like `pageTracker` are set before the `google-analytics.com/*.js` load, so unescaping `%3Cscript` and `%3E%3C/script%3E` is only the way for them.

just my 2 cents, sorry If I say wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Writing directly into the document without using the '<' or '>' characters means that you don't have to escape them in document formats which interpret these literally. Otherwise, the correct interpretation is that the `<script>` tags begin inside of the string, which is not what's desired.

Also, note that there's an error in your proposed alternative code (you missed a quote mark after the end of the `src` attribute).

Answer (score 0):

I think that:

```
document.wrIte('<script src="'"
```

will fail HTML Validation as well. Interestingly, it also breaks the Preview on this comment box :)