# Why Do Developers Split Up <script in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I see so many things like this:
    `S = "<scr" + "ipt language=\"JavaScript1.2\">\n<!--\n";`

Why do they do this, is there an application/browser that messes up if you just use straight `"<script>"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at this question:

[Javascript external script loading strangeness.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728697/javascript-external-script-loading-strangeness)

Taken from [bobince's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728697/javascript-external-script-loading-strangeness/729072#729072):

> To see the problem, look at that top
>   line in its script element:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     document.write('<script src="set1.aspx?v=1234"
>                            type="text/javascript"></script>');
> </script>
> ```
>
> So an HTML parser comes along and sees
>   the opening <script> tag. Inside
>   <script>, normal <tag> parsing
>   is disabled (in SGML terms, the
>   element has CDATA content). To find
>   where the script block ends, the HTML
>   parser looks for the matching
>   close-tag </script>.
>
> The first one it finds is the one
>   inside the string literal. An HTML
>   parser can't know that it's inside a
>   string literal, because HTML parsers
>   don't know anything about JavaScript
>   syntax, they only know about CDATA. So
>   what you are actually saying is:
>
> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     document.write('<script src="set1.aspx?v=1234"
>                            type="text/javascript">
> </script>
> ```
>
> That is, an unclosed string literal
>   and an unfinished function call. These
>   result in JavaScript errors and the
>   desired script tag is never written.
>
> A common attempt to solve the problem
>   is:
>
> ```
> document.write('...</scr' + 'ipt>');
> ```

This wouldn't explain why it's done in the start tag though.

Comment: Of note, this hasn't been a problem since the days of Netscape.  All modern browsers (including IE6 in this use of "modern") work "correctly" in this regard.  Unfortunately the same can't be said for the syntax hiliters in some editors...

Comment: Correctly means wrong in this case. Relying on such behavior makes it _very_ difficult to write new HTML/Javascript renders.

Comment: Just doing `<\/script>` is enough

Answer (score 0):

The more appropriate way to append scripts is to use the DOM.

1. Create an element of type `<script>`. See documentation for `document.createElement`.
2. Set its attributes (`src`, `type` etc.)
3. Use `body.appendChild` to add this to the DOM.

This is a much cleaner approach.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question at all.